# Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription fails

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 (and Update 5 CTP 2), Tools / Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription is failing immediately for me with an error:

"An error occurred during the sign in process: authentication_ui_failed: The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete for an unkown reason"

Any idea how to solve this problem? I can sign in through the Azure Portal just fine. I also tried adding a New Deployment in an Azure web project. It brings up the Deploy to Resource Group dialog but doesn't show anything in the Subscription pull-down. When I choose Manage in that menu, it brings up the Manage Microsoft Azure Descriptions dialog which shows I have a subscription with Subscription ID and User Account filled in with reasonable info.

There are several other places in VS to connect to Azure (eg, Server Explorer pane) but they all fail exactly the same way.

Someone else in my company is able to connect his VS 2013 to the same Azure subscription, though as a different user of course. His brings up a Connect to Visual Studio dialog. I think mine is trying to as I see a rectangular flash about the same size as this dialog an instant before getting the error message.

It appears that it is trying to access my Visual Studio account and that's failing. If I try to log out of it and back in, it displays a broken web page ("This page can't be displayed.") in a window with the URL: https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com. I tried visiting this page in Firefox, my default browser, and it loaded the page just fine. However, when I tried it in IE 11 I got the same "This page can’t be displayed" error page. I guess I need to focus on eliminating this problem first.

Any ideas on how to get past this?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this problem by resetting Internet Explorer's settings to defaults. Then IE could load https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com. VS 2013 was then able to connect to Azure.

Comment: I was receiving no error at all. The "Connect to Microsoft Azure Subscription" simply didn't do anything. This solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. Issue was in IE Security settings TLS 1.x were unchecked.

Just selecting TLS 1.x solved the issue.

Comment: how and where to set ?

Comment: @UsmanY
Start Internet Exporer
Goto Internet Options
Goto Advanced Tab
Under settings scroll to Security settings and select TLS 1.x protocols.

Comment: bless you sir.  8 hours of my life chasing this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off any Anti Virus softwares you have ON - that's what worked for me.